# Filter by third argument in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-contextual-filters

I am trying to create a Block View filtering by the path's (actually an alias) third argument, but can't succeed.

The path where the block is displayed is `sitename.com/first/second/third`.

Actually the third argument is the node's author, in the end, I am trying to display a block where only the content created be the author of the node the block is in... 
I.e: in the content type Garage node created by user Joe, there should be a block of content type Cars created by Joe. The node's path would then be `garagecars.com/garages/spain/joe`.

I have tried setting 3 `Global:Null` arguments and then `User:Uid` but it doesn't work.

[image: Caption of the Arguments in the View]

Help? Any other way to filter by node author? (have been a long while searching and the "filter by path arguments" approach seemed the good one, but I must be missing something then).

**UPDATE**: in the Views preview the path `garages/spain/joe` works but it doesn't in the page itself `http://garagecars.com/garages/spain/joe`... which has me ever more puzzled.

**SOLVED:** I was inserting the blog programatically throught the `views_embed_view($viewName, $display_id, $args)`... that's why it DID work on preview but when the page was rendered, the arguments set programmatically overrode the one's in the path, thus not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in the same question. Information provided on making this work.